# Regex nested groups

Tags: .net, regex

I am attempting to extract all data from a file with one regex expression. Since there are optional(`?`,`*`) and repitious(`*`,`+`) expressions, it would be difficult to enumerate through the captures, at least in a readable and understandable fashion. Therefore, I am using named groups. However the data is in an XML like structure; neseted elements can have complex elements. So I am using nested name groups. However, one I have captured a group, how do I retrieve the nested groups by name?

```
Dim mtch = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(fullText, _
                                       "\s+(?<PolyID>\d+)" & _
                                       "\s+(?<Center>" & _
                                            "(?<LAT>\-?\d\.\d+E\+\d{2})" & _
                                            "\s+(?<LON>\-?\d\.\d+E\+\d{2})" & _
                                        ")\n(?<Point>\s+" & _
                                            "(?<LAT>\-?\d\.\d+E\+\d{2})" & _
                                            "\s+(?<LON>\-?\d\.\d+E\+\d{2})" & _
                                        "\n)+END\n", _
                                        System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

I am trying to get the

```
mtch.Group("Center").Group("LAT").Value
```

How can I retrieve named subgroups of the current group?

Comment: Perhaps, don't use a regular expression -- [Now you have two problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html). Break up the problem into smaller pieces, using a small PC/recdec/ANTLR/whatever library or, if it can be mangled through a simple HTML (e.g. unstrict XML ;-) parser, etc, to get some ADT to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you rename your groups to "CenterLAT", "CenterLON", "PointLAT", and "PointLON".  You might be able to get what you want from the `mtch.Groups("Center").Captures` collection, but you can't index that collection by name.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Regex, have you considered using XSLT? or XLinq?

Comment: this is not an XML file. Its XML-Like, in the sense that nested elements (Groups) can have arbitrary complexity

Comment: @Frag How exactly is the file structured?

Comment: The format of the data is their own proprietary format. It doesnt follow any standard convention. However, the data structure is reliable in the sense that it follow THEIR convention.